# issues while installing texmaker

Tags: pdflatex, texmaker

```
vivek@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install texmaker
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gummi : Depends: libgtksourceview2.0-0 (>= 2.10.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgtkspell0 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: texlive-extra-utils but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
         Recommends: texlive-xetex but it is not going to be installed
 openssh-server:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libcomerr2:i386 (>= 1.01) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.12.1+dfsg-2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libkrb5-3:i386 (>= 1.13~alpha1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libpam0g:i386 (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libselinux1:i386 (>= 1.32) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libwrap0:i386 (>= 7.6-4~) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: zlib1g:i386 (>= 1:1.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: init-system-helpers:i386 (>= 1.18~)
                       Depends: openssh-client:i386 (= 1:6.9p1-1)
                       Depends: libpam-modules:i386 (>= 0.72-9) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: openssh-sftp-server:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: ncurses-term:i386
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
vivek@ubuntu:~$
```

I got the eroor while installing texmaker in ubntu operating system 
the details of terminal give above
try to resolve problem that i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the system by following linux command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

retype the command to again install it

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
```

and

for more packages

type

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-science
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```